# Zapier integration - how to send file via webhook

Tags: webhooks, zapier

I want to create a Zapier integration for our web service. It's an ASP.Net Core application.

One of the triggers will send file and some additional metadata with Zapier's REST hook. Is there any support for files in a Zapier Platform UI? How can I define a payload with file in a "Incoming webhook message" tester?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I asked Zapier directly by email, the outcome was that Zapier Platform UI does not support files today, so I need to re-implement my integration with Zapier CLI.